# Unable to load static image with react@16.4.2 component with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, urlloader

I am trying load static image in my component named as Top.js so i have import image like below in Top.js:

```
import logo from './images/logo.png'
```

path for logo.png is `frontend/src/images/logo.png` .
After that i am trying to use this in my JSX in component like below:

```
<img src="{logo}" alt="Homepage" />
```

Component is loading successfully but it is not showing logo image.
By following solution for similar kind of issues i have setup webpack configurations as well but it's still not working.

Here is my webpack configuration for dev environment.

path for webpack inside my root directory is as follow:

```
`frontend/node_module/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js`
```

by following the [link](https://blog.hellojs.org/importing-images-in-react-c76f0dfcb552) i did changes in config as :

```
test: /\.(pdf|jpg|png|gif|svg|ico)$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'url-loader'
                },
            ]
```

After that i started my app again with `npm start` and it started successfull but logo image is not showing.

I am using `react@16.4.2` for frontend with Koa.js backend and `node@10.8.0`

Comment: Do it as:  `src={logo}`.

Comment: haha it works. Thanks @SookieSingh

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Comment: Just provide this as an answer @SookieSingh and this comment won't be wasted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript expressions can be used inside of JSX. We just need to wrap it with curly brackets `{}`, but you are making it a String by wrapping them like this `"{}"`. Remove the `""` and it will work like a charm:

```
<img src={logo} alt="Homepage" />
```

[JSX In Depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html).